# How to hide only part of bootstrap sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I want to create an sidebar from 'vue-bootstrap' which been hidden on click, but I want to hide only 80% of width of this sidebar, so, how to hide only part of the sidebar?

```
<b-button v-b-toggle.sidebar-1 class="toogle-sidebar">
        <span>Toogle sidebar</span>
</b-button>


<b-sidebar
      id="sidebar-backdrop"
      title="Sidebar with backdrop"
      :backdrop-variant="variant"
      backdrop
      shadow
    >
      <div class="px-3 py-2">
        <b-form-group label="Backdrop variant" label-for="backdrop-variant">
          <b-form-select id="backdrop-variant" v-model="variant" :options="variants"></b-form-select>
        </b-form-group>
      </div>
    </b-sidebar>
```

I want to create something like in a Gitlab siddebar, when i click on `hide sidebar` then i see only icons of the menu,
can someone tell me how to do this?

thanks for any help!

Comment: I've worked with Vue 2 and Bootstrap 4, but not vue-bootstrap (search actually found bootstrap-vue).  In general, my approach would be to create two versions of the sidebar, and display the one you want via click events.  Possibly there is a best practices way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the `v-model` instead of the directive & attach a class to it: then you can use CSS animation to overwrite default CSS values:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      sidebar: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSidebar() {
      this.sidebar = !this.sidebar
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.b-sidebar-outer.closed #sidebar-backdrop {
  display: block !important;
  transform: translateX(-270px);
  animation-name: sidebarAnim;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.b-sidebar-outer:not( .closed) #sidebar-backdrop {
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation-name: sidebarAnim;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes sidebarAnim {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-270px);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Add this to <head> -->

<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the following for BootstrapVueIcons support -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
        <b-button @click="toggleSidebar">TOGGLE SIDEBAR</b-button>
      </b-col>
      <b-sidebar id="sidebar-backdrop" v-model="sidebar" title="Sidebar with backdrop" backdrop-variant :class="{ closed: !sidebar }" backdrop shadow>
        asdfsadf
      </b-sidebar>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</div>
```